# Do we lose attributes when we change difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay)

When we change difficulties in Diablo 2 from Normal to Nightmare, we lose some resistance.

Does the same mechanic apply to Diablo 3?

Comment: In the question that says "duplicate". there is no information about the penalties that you suffer (if you suffer any). So should I assume that you don't suffer any penalty at all?

Comment: One would hope that *all* of the differences between difficulties would be listed in the answers - if not, it's a bad answer. Either way, this is asking whether or not one specific difference exists, which means this is a subset of the linked question.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate. It is asking if a feature that existed in an older version of the game exists in the new game, while the linked question is asking what the difference is between difficulty levels. It doesn't seem to make sense to expect the answer for "How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?" to contain answers on if difficulty-specific features from an older version of the game exist or not.

Comment: Whether or not context exists from Diablo II doesn't really make a difference here - everything this question asks (and more) is already asked in the previously mentioned question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not lose anything by going up a difficulty level

I've played through Normal, Nightmare, and am in Hell now, and have not seen any decrease in my character's stats when changing difficulty levels.

Other things, such as life leech, are affected though. See [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66348/8462) for a full list of what is affected by diffculty