# How is life steal affected by difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay)

I've read life steal is weaker in higher difficulties, similar to how it behaves in Diablo II. What is the precise effect of the difficulty level on the life steal stat?

Comment: I posted my answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69894/8462) on the question listed as a duplicate :)