# Do harder difficulties reduce your resistances?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay)

Back in Diablo II, harder difficulties would cut some percentage points off your character's resistances (possibly making them negative).  I was wondering if the same thing happens in Diablo III.

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  There is basically nothing in that question or its answers that even come close to answering my question.

Comment: agree not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Diablo 3, resistances work like Armor.  It reduces damage from an element by a flat amount.  As you get to higher levels, the amount that gets reduced from same level monsters is reduced.  So 90 resist against a level 1 monster will reduce a lot more damage than 90 resist against a level 50 monster.

So, to answer your question, no, higher difficulties do not reduce your resistances directly.  Enemies are higher level, and therefore, your resistances are less effective.