# How is CC reduced in higher difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed that Leap with the Death from Above rune seems to stun normal monsters for a much longer time than champions in inferno.

Is there a CC length reduction against different mob types in the higher difficulties of Diablo 3? If so, how much of a reduction is it?

Comment: There is a CC length reduction but I only know from offhand comments and experience in game, if someone could find a solid citation with a nice table...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blizzard has a page detailing the [CC reductions per difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#difficulty-scaling) level.

The reductions only apply to rare,elite or boss monsters, not the normal variants, and they also get a small reduction on Normal difficulty which scales up a lot in Inferno.

Re. stun, the base duration of your `Leap`'s stun effect would be reduced to:

- 65% in Normal
- 50% in Nightmare
- 35% in Hell/Inferno

Also, with higher reduction it is easier to fall below the 'minimum threshold' (in this case 0.5s) below which no stun will be applied at all.

---

Kind of late, but I just saw this question and it doesn't have a good answer.

[How do monster level and act number affect crowd control reduction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/how-do-monster-level-and-act-number-affect-crowd-control-reduction) posted later is actually a dup of this.

Answer (score 4):

The CC reduction is increased by the level difference
And elites /champions have bonus CC reduction too.

When you are in inferno your level stays at 60 but the monster reach lvl 63
so they have naturaly CC reduction over you

don t know the numbers but maybe like 10% per lvl difference

so if elites have 50% base CC and lvl 63 => 65 % CC reduction

But the CC work differently with slow stun fear confusion

for the stun the CC reduction will affect duration
but for the slow it will affect the % movement speed reduction

80% slow for 8sec  == 65% CC reduc ==>  28% slow 8 sec

4 sec stun == 65% CC reduc ==>  1.4 sec

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Nop sry just based on my experience as a barbarian and witch Doctor And i assume it works exactly like the armor and resistance when you mouseover the armor you can read that this damage reduction is for a monster of your level

Comment: @RapidQA this has been annouced by Blizzard as to how CC from enemies affect players, I imagine it works the same the other way around. It is in the [1.0.3 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012#blog).

Answer (score -1):

Champions and Elites get a built-in reduction to CC. I don't know how much exactly, but it feels like 66% or worse. It's definitely frustrating for classes which rely on CC rather than evasion.

Answer (score -2):

Subtract 10% of the duration for each level of difficulty increase

Comment: Do you have a source?