# How do monster level and act number affect crowd control reduction?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I understand [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/how-is-cc-reduced-in-higher-difficulties) correctly, then each level a monster has on you gives them 5% reduction to CC? And elites in Inferno have a base 50% CC reduction?

Please tell me if this is correct:

- Act 1 Inferno (Level 61 monsters) - 55% reduction
- Act 2 Inferno (Level 62 monsters) - 60% reduction
- Act 3 and 4 Inferno (Level 63 monsters) - 65% reduction

**Edit:** From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay) I was able to find that champions in Inferno have a 65% stun resistance. Does this mean that they have 65% in all acts?

Also, do regular monsters have resistances?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated the main question based on your link.

Comment: Your new question is completely different from the original one; in cases like that, it's usually better to ask a new question than apply it to your current question.  Also, [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74511/do-monsters-have-defensive-stats-in-diablo-iii) might help you out.

Comment: Completely different? It's exactly on the same subject. What are you talking about?

Comment: "Do regular monsters have resistances?" and "How do CC effects work in Inferno?" are two entirely different questions.  I'm not sure how they could be related.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't understand the question, but CC effects are reduced by resistances. I was just asking if regular monsters are also effected.

Comment: Ok, I did misunderstand what you were asking; I thought you were asking whether regular monsters had resistances, period.  Sorry, my bad.  This is still a duplicate question, though; all you're asking for is clarification.  In that case, your best bet is to comment on question or answers, asking for that clarification.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The proposed duplicate http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay should not preclude specific questions about crowd control on inferno difficulty.

Comment: It's ok, I got the answer anyway.

Comment: You are right, but the people on this site have a weird mentality of wanting to close questions as duplicates because they are similar. Who well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is CC reduced in higher difficulties?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/how-is-cc-reduced-in-higher-difficulties). Relevant discussion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/vtc-on-a-question-that-was-reopened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal (white) monsters do not have any inherent Crowd Control reduction on any difficulty level (although they may get some reduction by virtue of being higher level than the character).  The amount of reduction that champion and higher monsters get is the same on all acts of a given difficulty level, again subject to variation based on the level difference between the monster and the character.  Unfortunately I don't know the specifics of how level difference affects reduction.

Comment: This is all I wanted to know, thanks. Sucks we don't have the exact numbers.

Answer (score 5):

CC effects (knockback, slow etc.) on elite & champion mobs are [reduced based on the difficulty level](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#difficulty-scaling), and also have minimum amounts to trigger them (e.g. if you do less than 21 yards knockback to a mob in Inferno, it will completely ignore the effect).

Note, the [Blizzard page](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty#monster-resistances) with details on the differences also mentions that

> Movement and attack speed reductions ... modify the **magnitude** of the effect, not its **duration**

(emphasis mine)