# Stat Priority for Monk/Barb in Inferno

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most optimal way to build Monk to in Inferno?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67564/what-is-the-most-optimal-way-to-build-monk-to-in-inferno)

I am wondering what sort of stats should I be focusing on for these melee classes to prepare them for act 1 & 2 of inferno? In addition, how much damage should I be doing?

I've been reading [this post](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149542120) about inferno barb, and I am wondering if it is still accurate with the latest patch. It states that ideally I should be at 800 resist, 10k armor, 20k damage, 35k health. Should I also be focusing on attack speed & life on hit weapons? I am also assuming I should be using a sword and board.

Similarly, for my monk I came across [this post](https://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4310135982) saying that ideally a monk should be running 450 resist, 7k armor, 11k damage, 35k health, 1k life on hit. Is this still a viable way of building a monk? Should I be dual wielding?

In addition, none of these posts focuses on critical damage/chance. Is that stat usually reserved for ranged classes?

Comment: and/or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69523/building-barbarian-in-inferno?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in inferno Act 1 and what I found for monk essential is using **all surviving skills** + has **400+ resistances for all element** by using its passive: **One With Everything**: (1 way of doing inferno)

Surviving skills including:

**Blinding Flash**: Use increase chance to let elite monsters misses

**Breath of Heaven** (I am using increase damage rune)

**Serenity**: (I am using increase duration rune)

**Mantra of Healing**: Use increase *resistance* one

Other skills are up to you ([build](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/monk#..YXgQ!U!...bYc))

While I also heard someone is using **LoH (Life on Hit)** to pass. They essentially increase damage and kill monsters within the serenity time, I am not sure about how they really work, but it is a good thought.

Hopefully those will help.

Comment: No problem, BTW you can check AH first, and if you cant, you can draw elite monsters to a entry of another map, and go back and forth to kill them using Serenity (kinda cheating though :\). Thats what I do when I only had 400 res on my monk.

Comment: Nice idea. I'll be sure to try it out.

Comment: The name Blizzard calls it is [Life on Hit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/how-does-life-on-hit-work) (LoH).